# Redirecting bad links to the correct links via htacess or 301 redirect plugin for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, 301-redirect

I'm getting a lot of 404 errors b/c I recently switched content management systems (Habari to WordPress). I would like to use the 301 redirect plugin for WordPress to capture and helpfully redirect the offending links to the correct urls. Here's an example of the type of errors I'm seeing and what they should be redirected to:

```
http://janetalkstech.com/admin/publish?id=146
```

should redirect to
        `http://janetalkstech.com/?p=146`

```
http://janetalkstech.com/admin/publish?slug=post-title
```

should redirect to 
        `http://janetalkstech.com/post-title`

I would greatly appreciate any specific pointers on how to perform the redirects with either the 301 redirect plugin for WordPress or via .htaccess file

Edit: Redirection plugin being used is the one by Urban Giraffe:
     `http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/`

Answer (score 1):

how many links ?

With redirection plugin, you can edit a link manually !

Other way, you find the file where links are stored (Redirection),
then a batch process with textwrangler (using Regex) to rewrite URL and it's done !

Sebastien

Answer (score 0):

What you want is URL rewrite (available through mod_rewrite in Apache).  This will translate one URL into a different URL.

To enable rewriting, put the following in your htaccess file:

`Options +FollowSymlinks` 
`RewriteEngine on`

Now you'll need to add the rewrite rules to htaccess.
Turn `http://janetalkstech.com/admin/publish?id=146` into `http://janetalkstech.com/?p=146`.

`RewriteRule ^admin/publish?id=(.*)  /?p=$1`